# C++ SendInput() failing after Sleep()

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble executing a SendInput() function after Sleep(). I have been looking for days for a solution and have come up empty handed. Here is my code:

```
void Form1::GenerateKey (int vk) {          
    INPUT ip;
    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.wScan = MapVirtualKey(vk,MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
    ip.ki.wVk = 0;
    ip.ki.time = 0;
    ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE; 
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

So when I do`Sleep(2000); GenerateKey(0x46);` it doesn't work but calling only `GenerateKey(0x46);` does.

It may also be worth mentioning that if I press a key while sleeping, it will work.

Comment: Define "doesn't work" exactly.  `SendInput()` merely injects the keystrokes into the same input queue that the keyboard driver inserts its events into.  Any timing issues are outside of `SendInput()`'s control.

Comment: BTW, 0x46 is `VK_F', ie the `F` key. When sending textual keystrokes, you should use `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE` instead of `KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. By "doesn't work" I mean that nothing happens. The code after GenerateKey is executed but no key is pressed.

Comment: [When something gets added to a queue, it takes time for it to come out the front of the queue](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140213-00/?p=1773)

Comment: Nice article and I understand that the input is sent to the queue but why would a Sleep before the function make a difference?

Comment: `Sleep()` allows other threads to run.  Maybe by the time the keystrokes are put into the queue and dispatched, another thread has gained input focus, rather than the thread you are expecting?  Another thing to consider is you should call `SendInput()` once with 2 `INPUT`s instead of calling it twice with 1 `INPUT` each, that way the two key events are more likely to travel through the queue back-to-back and other keystrokes don't get in between them.